# Formatting a line with spaces at the beginning

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Consider below piece of code

```
line = "I am writing a question"
print('{0: >10}'.format(line))
```

This does not work as expected. I expected output to be

```
'          I am writing a question'
```

I know I can achieve this by other means like printing the spaces first using one print statement and then print the sentence. But curious to know what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: _'Same piece of code will work if I assign line = "question".'_ So the output you get then is ten spaces followed by the word "question"? That's weird. It only outputs two spaces when I do it.

Comment: Right. My bad. I have edited the question. My assumption was that {0: >10} would add 10 spaces at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line is longer than 10 characters; the width is a minimal value and applies to the whole column. If you wanted to add 10 spaces, always, prefix these before the format:

```
print('          {0}'.format(line))
```

If you always wanted to right-align the string in a column of 33 characters (10 spaces and 23 characters for your current line), then set the column width to that instead:

```
print('{0:>33}'.format(line))
```

Now, when your `line` value is longer or shorter, the amount of whitespace will be adjusted to make the output 33 characters wide again.

Demo:

```
>>> line = "I am writing a question"
>>> print('          {0}'.format(line))
          I am writing a question
>>> print('{0:>33}'.format(line))
          I am writing a question
>>> line = "question"
>>> print('{0:>33}'.format(line))
                         question
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a built in method  :

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust

```
v = 'hi'
print v.rjust(4, ' ');
```

prints

```
 '  hi'
```

Comment: But `"I am writing a question".rjust(10)` will give the OP the same problem.

Comment: so u just want to print 10 empty spaces no matter the length of the string?

Comment: I'm not the OP, but that's what they are asking for.

Comment: well the spaces depends on the length of the string. I wanted my line to be 80 chars (spaces + text). The answer by Martijn solved the problem.